# Get rid of default view in Satchmo / Django?

Tags: python, django, satchmo

just curious what's the proper/transparent way to get plain 404 error instead of view for the pre-defined url ?

The default install of Satchmo handles `/quickorder` url with a cart view. I would like to completely disable handling for this url. So far I did get is the following url replacement in *url.py* at the top of store tree:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from satchmo_store.urls import urlpatterns
from satchmo_utils.urlhelper import replace_urlpattern

replace_urlpattern(
        urlpatterns,
        url(r'^quickorder/$', handler404)
    )
```

The `handler404` is from django.conf.urls.defaults but it returns Django's own content instead of the shop's default 404 page like if you would ask for a non-existent page like http://www.google.com/quickorder_somenonsenseintheurl.

Any idea how to override this while avoiding modifications of default Satchmo installation ?

Comment: Error page is usually modified only by writing a new template (copy any and edit) without writing a line of python. Did you tried to create a simple template for `shop/404.html` in your app? Is not it enough?